# Azure Functions .NET 5 Isolated HttpTrigger Path Variable Input Binding

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-5

I'm just trying to figure out how to do something in .NET 5 that worked in 3.1 and before.

In 3.1, the route variable binds correctly to the Guid parameter of the same name:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run(
[HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "records/{clientId:Guid}")] HttpRequest req,
Guid clientId,
ILogger log)
{
return new OkObjectResult(clientId);
}
```

A comparable .NET 5 version of this same function fails to bind the path variable:

```
[Function("Function1")]
public static HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", Route = "records/{clientId:Guid}")] HttpRequestData req,
Guid clientId,
FunctionContext executionContext)
{
var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
response.WriteString(clientId.ToString());
return response;
}
```

The error that is thrown is as follows:

> Exception:
> Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Diagnostics.Exceptions.FunctionInputConverterException:
> Error converting 1 input parameters for Function 'Function1': Cannot
> convert input parameter 'clientId' to type 'System.Guid' from type
> 'System.String'.

I can change the type of the parameter to string and then parse it into a Guid after the fact, of course, but I'd like to know if it's still possible to do it the aforementioned way.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things:

1. Why isn't the route constraint taken into account (i.e. why does a conversion need to occur)

I found a [related git issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2960). That doesn't seem to be fixed, though it makes me wonder how you managed to make it work with .NET Core 3.1 :)

2. Why isn't the input string automatically converted to a Guid

I had a look [at the code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/src/DotNetWorker.Core/Context/Features/DefaultModelBindingFeature.cs) to understand where the exception is raised.

The model binding is using a list of [`IConverter`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/src/DotNetWorker.Core/Converters/Converter/IConverter.cs) to convert between the input type and the binding type. In your case, the input type is `string` and the binding type is `Guid`, and there's no built-in converter that can do that. You can't even create your own `IConverter`, because it's an internal interface.

Note: here's an example of `IConverter` that converts a string to a byte array: [`StringToByteConverter`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/blob/main/src/DotNetWorker.Core/Converters/StringToByteConverter.cs)

So basically, there's nothing you can do apart from your suggestion to parse the Guid yourself.